# Is it normal that the amount of experience needed to level up is not the same between the pyromancer and the pirate class?

Tags: hero-siege

I am currently playing Hero Siege in Multiplayer Local and we face an issue. The Pyromancer's level is different than the Pirate's level.

- We start the game at level 1 together.
- We play strictly together.
- The Pirate does not seem to own an item to increase experience gain.
- We note the cap around the level 30~.
- The difference increases at each level.
- We mostly don't die.
- We play in Nightmare.
- We play on Steam.
- Steam says the the game is updated.

Current level:

[image: Current level]

The Pirate's cap to the level 39 is 50.3k.

[image]

The Pyromancer's cap to the level 35 is 74k.

[image]

The problem is troublesome because we find more and more items cap for the level 37 and higher. The pyromancer starts to be out of league. Is it a normal behavior? What can we do to mitigate this.

Note that I copy/paste this question on [steam](https://steamcommunity.com/app/269210/discussions/0/1812044473324626502/). I will update this post if I get an update there.